# Install SIS Graphics Driver to be used as a dual monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

Is there a way I could configure my laptop to use dual monitor ?

The complication arises because the laptop has ***Silicon Integrated Systems Graphics***, and I have to use [Antonio J. de Oliveira's](http://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/uk/software/xorg.php) driver to run in the normal resolution [1280*800].

To display in the external monitor [1024*768], it has to be connected before the X11 starts. This then causes the laptop's monitor to display the copy of the monitor [1024*768] which distorts the image in the laptop's monitor. Also it is displaying the copy in both  monitors and is not extending the display.

Is there a way I could correct this?

**Edited**

doing

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
```

I get

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
```

and doing

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-sis
```

I get

```
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sis                 1:0.10.3-3build2                        X.Org X server -- SiS display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb              1:0.9.4-2build2                         X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
```

Comment: sis graphics driver is installed by default in Ubuntu and you don't need to install it. It would be possible that it was removed by mistake. Edit your question and post the output of these commands: `lspci | grep VGA` and `sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-sis`. Reply

Comment: @Saur.K I have updated the question to added the results.

  As about the driver being installed by default, ubuntu could not detect the monitor by default and displayed in 1024*764 in default, which caused distorted displays. Once I installed the external driver, things started to appear normal.

Comment: I don't know the exactly how to solve this problem, but I think you've to manually configure `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file in order to make the things working. Hope these links would help you: 1.http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/sis.4.html  2.https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis

Answer (score 0):

I've stuggled with SIS graphics cards on Ubuntu, so I know your pain.  Arch Linux has got SOME support for SIS graphics card users, depending on what SIS chipset you are using.  You may not want to use Arch Linux, but the information here may be helpful as it has got some information on setting up the x.org config file for dual head display. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xf86-video-sis